# Read Colour Value from Datafile in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot vectors with different colours. The colour value is stored as a third column in the data file.

For example, let us say the datafile is "a.txt" contains

```
0.603358           2.022173          1
1.08929            2.039982          2
1.588976           2.040512          3
```

The typical plot is

```
plot 'a.txt' using 1:1:($2-$1):(0) notitle with vectors heads size screen 0.008,90 lc 2
```

The question is that how the "lc" takes the third column value?

Answer (score 0):

Use `linecolor variable`, it gets color from the last mentioned column.

```
plot 'a.txt' using 1:1:($2-$1):(0):3 notitle with vectors heads size screen 0.008,90 lc variable
```

[image]